# Select data from database in C# with two inputs

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a table which stores 2 data one is `std_id` and the other is `course`, I want to assign courses to students.
is there a way I use both of them to locate an instance of my table like the following code:

```
using (var context = new Domain.TaskManagerDbContext())
{
      var Assign = new Domain.TaskUser()
      {
          user_id = user.ID,
          task_title = task.Title
       };

       if (context.TaskUsers.Any(e => e.std_id == id && e => e.course == course)) return;
       context.TaskUsers.Add(Assign);
       context.SaveChanges();
}
```

for example, I want to locate an instance with `user_id: 123456` and `course: Calculus2`.
the code above doesn't work I don't know if it is possible to write a code such as above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't repeat the `e =>` bit

```
if (context.TaskUsers.Any(e => e.std_id == id && e.course == course)) return;
```